# How to oversample an array of n string elements into an array of m string elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random, oversampling

l would like to oversample an array of `n` element into an array of m elements such that `m > n`.

For instance let's take n=3

```
colors=['red','blue','green']
```

set m =7

What l'm looking for ?

```
 oversampled_colors=['green','blue','red','red','blue','green','blue']
```

Comment: You should provide any example of you trying this. Anyways, if you just want random oversampling in `oversampled` use `for` loop and set the `range` to your `m` value, then use `randint` from `random` module to randomly pick values from `colors`.

Comment: How it works for strings (in my case) . randint for int values

Comment: Your values are stings, but their indexes are ints and those are the things you use.

Comment: Ah yes l do understand thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.random.choice` seems to be what you are looking for

```
>>> colors=['red','blue','green']
>>> np.random.choice(colors, 7)
array(['red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green'], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: `random.choices(colors, k=7)` - `choice` is only one

Comment: @PatrickArtner You are probably thinking of the `random` module. `numpy.random` is similar but different. In particular, it is definitely `choice`. `choices` does not exist.

Comment: gosh - thanks for pointing that out, you already got the +1 :) consider it +2 now

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def fun(colors,n,m):
  colors1=[]
  while(len(colors1)<n):
      colors1.append(colors[random.randint(0,m-1)])
  return colors1
colors=['red','blue','green']
oversampled_colors=fun(colors,7,len(colors))
print(oversampled_colors)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it's not random. For m = 7 your just in the same order red blue green until you reach 7 colors

Comment: what about this @ericlardon

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

To sample **WITH** replacement (values can be repeated):

```py
>>> random.choices(['red','blue','green'], k=5)
['green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
```

---

Also, to sample **WITHOUT** replacement (values cannot be repeated):

```py
>>> random.sample(['red','blue','green'], k=3)
['blue', 'green', 'red']
```